# How to loop through multiple lists/dict?

Tags: python, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search, parallel

I have the following code which finds the best value of `k` parameter in the `KNNImputer`. Basically it is looping through the list of `k_value` and for each element, it is fitting the `KNNImputer` to the model and in the end appending the result to an empty dataframe.

```
lire_model = LinearRegression()
k_value = [1,3,5,7,9,11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
k_value_results = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['k', 'mse', 'rmse', 'mae', 'r2'])

scoring_list = ['neg_mean_squared_error', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error', 'r2']

for s in k_value:
    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = s)   
    
    imputer.fit(train_x1_num)
    train_x2 = pd.DataFrame(imputer.transform(train_x1_num), columns = train_x1_num.columns)
    test_x2 = pd.DataFrame(imputer.transform(test_x1_num), columns = test_x1_num.columns)
    
    enc = ce.CatBoostEncoder()
    enc.fit(train_x3, train_y)
    train_x4 = pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(train_x3), columns = train_x3.columns)
    test_x4 = pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(test_x3), columns = test_x3.columns)

    base_score = cross_validate(lire_model, train_x4, train_y, cv = 5, scoring = scoring_list, 
                                n_jobs = -1)
    
    row = {
            'k': s,
            'mse' : -1 * base_score['test_neg_mean_squared_error'].mean(),
            'rmse' : -1 * base_score['test_neg_root_mean_squared_error'].mean(), 
            'mae' : -1 * base_score['test_neg_mean_absolute_error'].mean(), 
            'r2' : base_score['test_r2'].mean()
          }
    
    k_value_results = k_value_results.append(row, ignore_index = True)
```

If I have more than 1 list through which I want to loop through and perform the same functionality as above code, how can I do that?

For example:-

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d]
list2 = [e, f, g]
```

I want to loop through both the lists and for each combination of parameters (total 4*3 =12 combinations) I want the results. Basically I want to GridSearch over multiple lists without using sklearns GridSearchCV function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ParameterGrid` class from scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html) for this. This allows you to supply a dictionary where the values are lists with possible values for that specific key. You can iterate over this to get all possible combinations between the specific hyperparameters, see also the examples from the documentation page:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
param_grid = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [True, False]}
list(ParameterGrid(param_grid))
# [{'a': 1, 'b': True}, {'a': 1, 'b': False},
#  {'a': 2, 'b': True}, {'a': 2, 'b': False}]
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I can define the search space but how do I include it in my for loop? Do I use one iterator or 2?

Comment: Ok I did some Googling and finally it works now. I just used one iterator and it did the job.

Comment: Although a GridSearchCV for this purpose would have been nice and simple, the only reason I didn't use it is I don't know how to:P I know how to use it for model hyperparameter tuning but to do the same thing for something like an Imputer or an Encoder, is it even possible?

Comment: You can use the [`Pipeline` class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to create a single pipeline that contains both your imputer/encoder, any other preprocessing steps and the estimator you want to use and then combine it with the `GridSearchCV` class as shown [in this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html).